# javascript menu not performing correctly in explorer 8 (works fine in chrome and explorer 8 compatability mode)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, menu, explorer

i'm building a website template which you can see here:

http://davewallace.net/sunschool/template-test.asp

all was going well until i checked in explorer (8) on pc (i normally use chrome on pc)

the problem relates to the (left hand) side menu...

i noticed that upon clicking a second parent item in the side menu (that is during one session, clicking on one parent menu item after clicking on another) and every successive parent menu items clicked, the contents of the former parent menu that was clicked would not disappear when they should, instead staying on screen but moving up, aligned with the top parent item. all works fine in chrome however, this is only in explorer.

*** update! *** i just did some more research and viewed the page again in explorer running "compatibility mode" and it worked fine! so i have isolated the problem down to explorer 8  running in standard mode only.

another update * *thanks to Ibu, I have fixed a couple of (relatively minor) html errors which she thought may have been causing the problem. unfortunately this was not the case **** I believe it is a javascript issue and probably some kind of code clash between side menu and top menu code... I really am trying to do my best to resolve this but would love a bit of javascript guruness to rain down please :)

i note that it is almost definitely a code clash with code used to display the top menu dropdowns. i know this because i've used the sidemenu code before on a site by itself (without other dropdown menu code) and it works fine in both chrome and explorer.

i have included a link to the code below - it is all fairly well organised* and hopefully easy for someone to help me debug!

http://davewallace.net/stack-overflow/code.zip

the side menu javascript is css-dropdowns.js and i suspect it is something in this file that needs to be amended

*unfortunately some of the code in this file does not have line breaks and may be hard to read. i apologise for this. i did not write the code :)

the other javascript files all relate to the top menu.

thanking you in advance,

hope its not too tricky!

best regards,

dw

Comment: please post the relevant part of code. You shouldnt have people download stuff to help you. Here is what i suggest, show the part of the code that handles the animation of the left menu bar.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i'm sorry. i believe the code is too long to paste in here. so here is the direct link to the code  http://davewallace.net/sunschool/css/css-dropdowns.js if you click on it in most browsers it should display instantly...scroll-click in chrome to see in new tab...

Comment: the problem is the html not the javascript. [here are All the Errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdavewallace.net%2Fsunschool%2Ftemplate-test.asp&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) with suggested fixes

Comment: just confirming the errors have been fixed. It now gets a 100% pass at http://validator.w3.org http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdavewallace.net%2Fsunschool%2Ftemplate-test.asp

Comment: just updating this: HTML errors have been fixed. Problem still exists. Can anyone please help. Here is direct link to the code which handles left hand side menu animation: http://davewallace.net/sunschool/css/css-dropdowns.js

Comment: Hi @willis, i just went through your link using IE 6, and everything seems to be working. did you finally found a solution?

Comment: Hi @Ibu, IE 6? as clearly stated it's IE 8 where the problem occurs (and only in normal mode not compatibility mode) and it definitely still happening. here's a screen-shot of what you see after clicking on a few menu items: http://davewallace.net/stack-overflow/screen-shot-explorer8-standard-mode.png

Comment: I'm wondering if I should re-post this as a clean new problem now that the HTML errors have been corrected and because at the moment its getting too long and maybe people are put off by that! i have a deadline to get this fixed in the next 18 hours....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" it myself!! Yaaay

Whilst I know its not the most perfect solution, it works, and thats good enough for me considering how much time I've spent on this and the fact that I'm not getting paid to build this website!

Am a bit surprised no-one else could suggest this, anyway I worked it out for myself so I hope i get a few boy scout points :)

The solution was as follows:

Added the following to my head content:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

Hey Presto. IE 8 now emulates IE 7 and the problem is fixed.

Of course ultimately I know that there is still some issue in the code that IE 8 does not like, and if anyone cares to point it out to me, I'd be most grateful. But for now, I'm a happy chappy. Thanks @Ibu for your assistance earlier on in helping me clean up those HTML errors!

Comment: this is not a soulution... IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Ok since i went through your test page to see what the problem is, the javascript is the least of the problem:

Having incorrect html will cause other issues.

here is what i found in the console:

```
<head> must be a child of <html>. Content ignored. template-test.asp:7
Extra <html> encountered.  Migrating attributes back to the original <html> element and ignoring the tag. template-test.asp:28
<meta> is not allowed inside <div>. Moving <meta> into the <head>. template-test.asp:29
Unmatched </li> encountered.  Ignoring tag. template-test.asp:69
```

so fixing those error will very likely fix your other js errors

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. There was an extra <html> tag inside one of my includes. I removed it. It did not fix the problem. But thankyou anyway. I would suggest the best clue is the fact that it works in Explorer 8 in compatibility mode... And something to do with javascript controlling visibility of sub-menus...

Comment: compatibility mode tries to fix some of the errors for you. you still have an unclosed UL tag at the end of your list. this is very likely to be the problem.

Comment: I have corrected the html errors but this has not made a difference - the problem as described still exists.... the code zip file as referenced above has also been updated

Comment: just updating this: HTML errors have been fixed. Problem still exists. Can anyone please help. Here is direct link to the code which handles left hand side menu animation: http://davewallace.net/sunschool/css/css-dropdowns.js

Comment: since i'm new here, maybe i'm doing something wrong? shall i click the down arrow corresponding to answer above since it does not solve the problem? please help...

Comment: since nobody has answered me, i guess i'll have to decide for myself. i will try clicking the down arrow for the answer above since, whilst it helped me fix a few html errors, it is overall not useful as it did not fix the problem. if anyone disagrees please advise...

Comment: oh i see, i cannot "vote down" as i do not have enough reputation points.. oh well. please can someone out there help me!!! the problem still exists.. can someone at least give me a pointer towards where to look in the code to try to fix....